# How to put multiple conditions on a field, using Views 3?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to make **multiple conditions** on a field in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I found [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) that allows only one condition.

I also found [Views Custom Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_conditions), which I still don't really find how to use (very few documentation and the one left is very confusing to me).

So I'd like to find out **How to put multiple conditions on one field, using Views 3**.

Comment: Thank for you answer. In fact'd like to Show the number of images contained each node in the view. The image field has a default image attached if the user does not uplaod one. The number that I want to display depend on 3 conditions : 1. If the file has the precised id of the default image then "0 image" 2. if the number of image is one "1 image" 3. If the number of images in greather than 1 then "x images". I have tried it will views_conditional (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) which give me only one condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider module [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) (which only has a dev version today). Excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR conditions for contextual filters.

A few issues on Drupal.org that may be of some help:

- [Using OR in filters breaks contextual filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1367304).
- [Views AND/OR Contextual filters two ways](https://www.drupal.org/node/1451218).

There is also [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1111722#comment-9663681) in the support forum.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this too.